# Batch File Calling Node.js - How to Set ERRORLEVEL From Node

Tags: node.js, batch-file, errorlevel

I've got a batch file that calls a node program:

```
@echo off

echo Starting Deploy.js: %date% %time%
echo CurrentDir: %CD%

node .deploy/deploy.js
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto error

echo Finished Deploy.js: %date% %time%

echo %~n0: Completed %date% %time%

goto end

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
```

I'd like to be able to have my node.js program be able to have it hit the error condition on failure of the application.

How do I trigger that in node.js?

I tried having my main function return 0 or 1, but it's not automatically setting the ERRORLEVEL.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `process.exit(666)` ?

Comment: Trying it now, thanks!

Comment: @npocmaka It worked, do you want to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) about process object .In your case you'll not need a callback function so you can simply use:

```
process.exit(666);
```

where you can set your desired exit code instead of `666`